# MariaDB C++ Connector errors when attempting connections from multiple threads

Tags: c++, mysql, mariadb

Using the [MariaDB C++ Connector](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-cpp) on ubuntu 20.04, and gcc compiler. During load test of a webserver application it was discovered that anytime there was more than a single concurrent connection the server would crash. This was narrowed down to the connect member of the mariadb driver. The errors that were being reported were always one of the following two:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
Aborted (core dumped)
```

As it wouldn't be feasible to post the source of the server, I have reproduced a minimal working example that uses only standard library and `mariadb/conncpp.hpp`:

```
#include <mariadb/conncpp.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

sql::Driver* driver = sql::mariadb::get_driver_instance();
sql::SQLString connectionUrl = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/the_database_name";
sql::Properties properties = {{"user", "the_username"}, {"password", "the_password"}};

int main()
{
    // simulate 2 concurrent connections each making 500 requests
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> t1cbs;
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> t2cbs;
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) // if does not fail for you at 500 up the number until it does
    {
        t1cbs.push_back([&]{
            std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> conn(driver->connect(connectionUrl, properties));
            std::cout << "t1:" << conn->getHostname().c_str() << std::endl;
        });

        // comment out this block to keep the second thread from executing, and you will see 
        // that no errors occur
        t2cbs.push_back([&]{
            std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> conn(driver->connect(connectionUrl, properties));
            std::cout << "t2:" << conn->getHostname().c_str() << std::endl;
        });
    }

    std::thread t1([&]{
        for(auto& cb : t1cbs)
            cb();
    });

    std::thread t2([&]{
        for(auto& cb : t2cbs)
            cb();
    });

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Curious if there's something perhaps I'm not seeing that's going on that someone else might be able to point out? Although after going through the documentation, it seems pretty straight forward...the only thing maybe is that something's going on in the `driver->connect` that's not thread safe maybe? Not sure...quite confused...any ideas greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
After some more research I discovered the [following example](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-cpp/blob/master/test/driver_test.cpp#L52) where it's mentioned that if you have multiple threads then issues could occur...however still trying to figure out how one might circumvent this.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_thread_safe/ seems to contain useful information, as well as pointers to mysql_thread_init.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't believe that documentation pertains to the connection library in question, unless I misunderstand.

Comment: It is unlikely that the C++ library is a from-the-grounds-up reimplementation. It is almost a certainty that it's just a C++ wrapper for the real client library. The C++ library is unlikely to be keeping track of which execution threads it is getting invoked from. As such, it's on the C++ code to make sure of any thread safety-related arrangements. It shouldn't take an eternity to add mysql_thread_init and mysql_thread_end, to each execution thread, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It looks like there is a race condition in postConnectionQueries().

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik: mysql_thread_init isn't needed anymore, it's deprecated since MariaDB Connector/C 3.0.0. See https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/blob/3.3/libmariadb/mariadb_lib.c#L4255

Comment: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONCPP-105 There was the bug in the connector. Currently fixed and closed, yet to be released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in Connector/C++.
To track progress, please check https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONCPP-105